# SQL Server Reporting Services Datasource keeps losing database login credentials

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, reportingservices-2005

In my development environment, every time I reboot windows (which must be done at least daily for me), all of my Shared SSRS Datasources lose their credentials.

Currently I have them set up to log into the database using a fixed credential, but on reboot all the datasources pop over to using no credentials.  Granted, it's only in the dev environment, and I can just check out/update the datasource/check back in and it will work fine... until I reboot again.

FYI, I've been using these Shared Datasources for at least 2 years and no problems, but in the last month or so, it's been a recurring daily problem.

Help?

Comment: We've been experience the same problem where i work.  i'm interested in see if anyone has an answer.  do you use source safe?

Comment: Yup, we use SourceSafe, but like I said above, we didn't have any troubles for 2+ years, now it's every day.  Frustrating.

Comment: yeah.  we had ours set up for about half a year before it started doing this.  did you guys update anything recently?

Comment: There is an open bug on MSconnect for this issue; are you using sql 2005 / sp3 ? If it impacts you can i suggest you boost the rating on the bug it does say ms are investigating it so will speed them up. (http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=450753)

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you are talking about the Shared Data Sources in a Report Server project in Visual Studio, as opposed to a Data Source created directly on Reporting Services.  The latter, the data is stored all in the ReportServer database that was specified when setting up SSRS.

Now, as for the .rds file used in Visual Studio, if you open the file up in a text editor, notice that the username and password is not stored in the file.  It is actually stored in the .rptproj.user file.  So, check that someone didn't remove the .user file from source control (.user files *shouldn't* be in source control, but in your case...).

This is scenario is testable by entering your credentials, saving all files, and exiting Visual Studio.  Find and delete the .rptproj.user file, and open your Report Server project up again and see the credentials gone!

A work around is add the "User ID=user;Password=pass" as part of the Connection String.  When the .rds is opened up, the Connection String won't show this portion, but the Credentials tab should have the right values.

Comment: Totally doesn't work.  Tried adding new datasources, they lose credentials.  I've added the user credentials to the connection string, and it gets knocked out (although the credentials are then transferred to the credentials area of the datasource).

Comment: did you check your .rptproj.user file as per my first suggestion?

Comment: I came across this disappearing credential issue while using TFS source control. Modifying the connection string to contain the login credentials only works when first entered; checking the project user file into source control is the real solution that fixes this issue and allows the credentials to be present for anyone that subsequently checks out the solution/project from source control.

Comment: Why do you guys keep talking about source control?  What the heck does that have to do with this?  We don't source control our data sources, nor the data source credentials, and you probably shouldn't either.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be related to the boot order of services on your machine.

Just a guess: Maybe there is new functionality in SP3 that checks if the connection credentials are valid. If they are not valid they are cleared.

The problem would then happen if this check is done before SQL server has had time to start. This would explain why they are cleared when the machine restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently experienced the same problem, but I can't connect it to a reboot.  It seemed to happen when I checked the solution from source control - we use Team Foundation Server.  After disabling the service account a bazillion times, it somehow healed itself and began behaving.  I found this post and checked my project folder for the rptproj.user file that benson mentioned, and it has a modified date of the day I had problems, but a create date of close to what I can remember as having created the project, so I will pay attention to this in the future.

Did anyone come up with anything new on this issue?

Comment: It was solved for me when I added the project's user file to TFS source control. Apparently the login credentials for the data source are contained in this file. Not ideal since it's against convention to have user based information under source control, but it works. I've also seen this solution needed when needing to have shared debug settings for a project.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you may have read this already, but something here could help?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159846.aspx

I would pay attention to how the SSRS was installed and also what accounts the servies run as, as well as an domain logon policies.